# Zend Paginator and Routes

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route, zend-paginator

I have read that I would need to setup a route to keep the values in the URL.
That's the application.ini example showed in the zendframework reference guide:

```
routes.example.route = articles/:articleName/:page
routes.example.defaults.controller = articles
routes.example.defaults.action = view
routes.example.defaults.page = 1
routes.example.reqs.articleName = \w+
routes.example.reqs.page = \d+
```

How could I instantiate the object with the config above and use it in my bootstrap? 
Example:

```
  $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                    'product/:id',
                    array(
                        'module' => 'default',
                        'controller' => 'product',
                        'action' => 'detail',
                     ),

    );
    $router->addRoute('product', $route);
```

Comment: I really don't see the need of this configuration for a paginator. Anyway you have to be more specific in order to get an answer.

Comment: @aurelio-de-rosa I've been configuring my routes in the bootstrap, I won't mess it up inserting routes in another places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, the second array param received by the zend controller router router are the variable requirements.

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                'articles/:articleName/:page',
                array(
                    'module' => 'default',
                    'controller' => 'articles',
                    'action' => 'view',
                    'page' => 1
                 ),
               array(
                    'articleName' => '\w+',
                    'page' => '\d+'                     
                 )

);
$router->addRoute('example', $route);
```

Comment: Exactly what I meant with my comment.